# Android java accessing URL from a string rather than hard coded

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access an image via URl using the below code:

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.details_list);

    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView txtLdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longdesc);
    SmartImageView imgPreview = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

    imgPreview.setImageUrl(lpreview);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("title");
    String ldesc = i.getStringExtra("longdesc");
    String lpreview = i.getStringExtra("preview");

    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(product);
    txtLdesc.setText(ldesc);
```

I am passing the "preview" value from another activity.  This contains the URL from which I want to grab the image, but it varies from user selection in the previous activity.  In `imgPreview.setImageUrl`, I would like to set that to the string `lpreview`, rather than hard coding it.

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with the code above is that you need to call setImageUrl after getting the string from the extras.  What isn't working with it?

Comment: You're already getting that from the previous activity right? It aint hardcoded at all. Just that you need to move your `imgPreview.setImageUrl(lpreview);` to below this line of code `String lpreview = i.getStringExtra("preview");`.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I'll try that now.  I tried reorganizing earlier and it was not working.  I'll try again.  Well, that worked!  thanks everyone!  Not sure where I was going wrong earlier.  Oh well, thanks for helping out a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, getIntent value before initialized your setContentView()

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent i = getIntent();

// getting attached intent data
String product = i.getStringExtra("title");
String ldesc = i.getStringExtra("longdesc");
String lpreview = i.getStringExtra("preview");
this.setContentView(R.layout.details_list);

TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView txtLdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longdesc);
SmartImageView imgPreview = (SmartImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

imgPreview.setImageUrl(lpreview);


// displaying selected product name
txtProduct.setText(product);
txtLdesc.setText(ldesc);
```